# How to create an ML pipeline for model retraining and inference [Kubernetes]

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-cronjob

I am working on a task where I need to design an ML pipeline for model retraining and inference on `Kubernetes`

I read some articles and watched some tutorials, with the help of which I have created 2 apps as described below

- For Model retraining, I have scheduled a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) (`Flask App #1`)
- For inference, I have created a separate flask app (`Flask App #2`)

I don't know how can we transfer the latest trained model from `CronJob` to the inference flask app

I am a newbie in Kubernetes any suggestion would be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make  use of the **Google Persistent Disk**, **[Kubernetes Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)** and **[Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims)** to do so.

I tried replicating a scenario where a Cronjob updates a text file with current time and date each time it creates a Pod. I then created a separate Pod outside the Cronjob to access this text file and was successful. Below are the steps I followed,

1. Create a Standard Persistent Disk on GCP using the following gcloud command,

   ```
   gcloud compute disks create pd-name   --size 500G   --type pd-standard   --zone us-central1-c
   ```
2. Then create a Kubernetes Persistent Volume using the above PD and a Persistent Volume Claim, so that the pods can request for storage on the Persistent Volume using the following configuration,

config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv
spec:
  storageClassName: "test"
  capacity:
    storage: 10G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pv-claim
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: pd-name
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: "test"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10G
```

3. Deploy a [Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) with the PVC configuration and which writes the current time and date into a text file stored on the PV using the following configuration,

Cronjob.yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: pv-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: pv-claim
          containers:
            - name: container
              image: nginx
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: "/usr/data"
                  name: pv-storage
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - date >> /usr/data/msg.txt
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

[Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) for more information.

4. Deploy a Pod with the same PVC configuration to check whether data added by the Cronjob pods is visible through this pod using the following configuration,

Readpod.yaml:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: readpod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: read-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/data"
          name: pv-storage
```

5. Then use [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) command to get a shell to a running container on the above Pod, by using the following commands and we should be able to view the text file in which the cronjob was updating time and date.

   ```
        $ kubectl exec -it  readpod -- /bin/bash
        $ cd usr/data
        $ cat msg.txt
   ```

You can make use of the above concepts and modify the configuration according to your use case.